# I need to accurately find the form response id using google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a simple form and I want to forward the response pages to my email address so I can click through straight to the result of that form submission. Using the code below it gives me a form response ID but it doesn't match the actual response ID in the URL when I navigate there on google forms. The form ID works

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  //get entry id
  var entryId = e.response.getId();

  //get form ID
  var formId = e.source.getId();

  var soloResponse = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/" + formId + "/edit#response=" + entryId

   //build email from form data
  var email = "test";
  var subject = "test";
  var body = soloResponse;

  //send email
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);

}
```

Comment: Having the same issue! Did you find a way to fix it? e.source.getId(); gives me a completely different ID than the ID used in the URL when I open it manually.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to create your own url to go to the entered response

the [class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getEditResponseUrl()) has a function `getEditResponseUrl()` which returns the full edit url of that response

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  //build email from form data
  var email = "test";
  var subject = "test";
  var body = e.response.getEditResponseUrl();

  //send email
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);

}
```

but if you want, you can still manually create your edit link like this:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  //get entry id
  var entryId = e.response.getId();

  //get form ID
  var formId = e.source.getId();

  var soloResponse = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/" + formId + "/viewform?edit2=" + entryId;

   //build email from form data
  var email = "test";
  var subject = "test";
  var body = soloResponse;

  //send email
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);

}
```